# Как передать информацию из input в react

Tags: reactjs, vk-mini-apps

Есть класс App

В него нужно вывести результат из input

В `constructor`

```
this.state = {
  filter_search: ''
};
this.onChangeSearch = this.onChangeSearch.bind(this);
```

Функция

```
onChangeSearch(e) {
  console.log(e);
}
```

Дальше в rendre я подключаю view самого фильтра

```
<Filter
  id="filter"
  go={this.go}
  filter_search={this.state.filter_search}
  onChangeSearch={this.onChangeSearch}
/>
```

И передаю в нее функцию с переменной

В `Filter`

```
const Filter = props => (
  <Input
    value={props.filter_search}
    onChange={props.onChangeSearch}
    top="Поиск" />
);
export default Filter;
```

Но когда я открываю окно Filter и ввожу любую букву, она не отображается в поле и в консоль приходят пустые значения
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Где я допустил ошибку?

Пример https://codesandbox.io/embed/inspiring-golick-5l4wf

Вроде как разобрался

Подставил в `onChangeSearch(e)`

```
this.setState({ filter_search: e.target.value });
```

Вроде как все работает работает, но правильно ли я сделал?
С React работаю в первые, хочется разобраться

Comment: Первая ошибка буква i `input`-а с большой буквы написали покажите код в `codesandbox` посмотрю.

Comment: @ИзбытокСусликов Подправил вопрос, добавил пример

Comment: Все же работает в чем проблема ? https://codesandbox.io/s/inspiring-golick-5l4wf?from-embed

Comment: @ИзбытокСусликов Я разобрался как сделать, когда добавлял код в `codesandbox`.

Comment: Очень рад!Напишите ответ на свой вопрос  в чем было  проблема и как решили потом примите свой ответ.Удачи.